# Guidance for this?? I have no idea even to get started.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

This is a question I have for an assignment and I have no idea how to get started. Help wanted! :)

Let S be the sphere centered at $(3, 0, 4)$ and of radius $2\sqrt 3$. Determine the pointnormal equations of the planes tangent to the sphere $S$ and orthogonal to the line $L : (x, y, z) = (4, 11, 7) + t(1, −1, 1)$. (ON-system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Take a line $R$ parallel to $L$ and passing through the center of the sphere.

Take the intersections of this line with the sphere (two points)

The planes tangent to the sphere at these two points are orthogonal to the line $R$ and also to the line $L$.

---

Added:

The line $R$ has equation: $(x,y,z)^T=(3,0,4)^T+t(1,-1,1)^T \qquad (1)$

The sphere has equation: $(x-3)^2+y^2+(z-4)^2=12 \qquad (2)$

To find the points of intersection substitute $(1)$ in $(2)$, this gives:
$$
[(3+t)-3]^2+(-t)^2+[(4+t)-4]^2=12 \iff t^2 = 4 \iff t=\pm 2
$$
The points of intersection of $R$ with the sphere are $A=(5,-2,6)^T$ and $B=(1,2,2)^T$

Since the vector direction of $R$ is $\vec r=(1,-1,1)^T$ the plane passing in $A$ and orthogonal to $R$ has equation:

$$
(\vec x-\vec A) \cdot \vec r=0 \iff (x-5)-(y+2)+(z-6)=0
$$

so the equation of this plane is $x-y+z=13$. And in the same manner you can find the other plane corresponding to $t=-2$.

Comment: Thank you. Hope this will get me somewhere :) gonna try to look at it.

Comment: I've seen that you have posted another related question. So I've added a solution here. I hope it's useful... and I suggest that you delete the other question. :)

Comment: Thanx! Now i might get somewhere, have been working for hours this morning, and Im not that far from solving it I think, but this will probably do the trick. I have been trying to toss and turn all of my knowledge to find what to do with this, and thank you! Now I'll probably get it done, and also learn from it :)

Comment: Yes I had to post another one, since Ive been working with what you said for hours but did not get to a solution yet, so i needed more info. Thank you again!

Comment: I deleted the new question too since i now think i can solve it